# GCC tool for size analysis?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I develop for embedded platforms by using GCC (arm-none-eabi-gcc). For size analysis, I use: arm-none-eabi-size and the .map file.

Because I'm having problems about size of my code, my question is: Is there any tool for size analysis more powerful? Any with statisticts or size by files? Or with the possibility to order functions by size?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: GCC has a parameter that will output all the memory/stack/etc details at the end of each file compiled. '-p' '-pg' '-a' '-fmem-report' '-ax'  I find the -fmem-report to be most useful to me.

Comment: you might want to look at the '-o' options and the related family of '-f' options when optimizing for size and/or speed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `arm-none-eabi-objdump -t Application.elf`. It will show you the size of all functions and global variables (as hex number).

```
address    type section size     name
------------------------------------------------
0000d600 l     F .text  00000198 uip_arp_update
```

Global variables are in `.bss` section, functions are in `.text` section and constant data is in `.data` section.

You can also use `arm-none-eabi-size *.o` in appropriate directory to see sizes of all intermediate files.

It is also possible to use `nm` tool

`arm-none-eabi-nm -t d -S --size-sort Application.elf`

---

It is also usefull to use `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` as compile parameter and `-Wl,--gc-sections` as linker parameter so it will delete all unused functions and data from your binary.

Comment: Thanks a lot of. For now, this is sufficient for me. Anyway, I think I need more flash space because the code size report is quite ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could customize your GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for that purpose.

The `justcountipa` pass in the `xtramelt-ana-simple.melt` file is doing something similar (count the Gimple instructions in functions)